# How can I get extract cross-validation accuracy after training in caret

Tags: r, r-caret

I'm using caret to build classification model. ROC is used as the metric to tune hyperparameters.

```
data("segmentationData")
train_control <- trainControl(method="cv", number=10, classProbs =TRUE,
                              summaryFunction = twoClassSummary)
grid = expand.grid( mtry = c(1,2,3))
output <- train(Class~., data=segmentationData, trControl=train_control,
                tuneGrid = grid, method="rf", metric='ROC', verbose=FALSE )
```

My questions is how I can get the cross-validation accuracy after training, when I use ROC as the metric? Thanks

Comment: take a look at `?train`: `output$results` contains the mean and SD for each hyper parameter combination. If you want to get the resample predictions and calculate more metrics based on that you can set: `savePredictions = "final"` or `"all"` in `trainControl`.

Comment: @missuse   thanks a lot. I cannot calcualte more metric from resample predictions, because output$pred do not provide any info about which observation are those predictions from.

Comment: in Classification `output$pred` has the column `obs` which is the true label, the columns named according to your target levels which represent predicted probability, the column rowIndex which represent the row number from the original data frame as well as the column Resample which tells you which resample instance the observation was in. Additionally there are hyper parameter combinations for each row. I gather that's plenty of info to calculate any metric

Comment: @missuse  I got it. Thanks a lot!